# How can I casting void * to void **?

Tags: c++, nrf52

I make some project to using nRF52833 by CPP.

I need to add NUS(Nordic Uart Service) in my project. But I have some problem.

Nrf library NUS using ble_nus.c file.
I try to build by CPP compiler but some error occur.

Error message is this.
Error[Pe167]: argument of type "void *" is incompatible with parameter of type "void **" C:\git\heden_ble\src\components\ble\ble_services\ble_nus\ble_nus.c 139

ble_nus.c file has four error points.

How can I casting void * to void **

```
ble_nus_client_context_t * p_client = NULL;

err_code = blcm_link_ctx_get(p_nus->p_link_ctx_storage, p_ble_evt->evt.gap_evt.conn_handle, (void *) &p_client);

ret_code_t blcm_link_ctx_get(blcm_link_ctx_storage_t const * const p_link_ctx_storage, uint16_t const conn_handle, void ** const pp_ctx_data)
```

Using CPP static_cast, reinterpret_cast.
I expect to build ble_nus.c

Comment: `p_client` is already a pointer. When you takes it address, e.g.  `&p_client` the type is `ble_nus_client_context_t**`. Your cast with `(void *) &p_client` is casting to `void*`  (legal in C), not `ble_nus_client_context_t**` - so you must account for the additional level of indirection when you cast back from `void*`.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Is it not `ble_nus_client_context_t**`? Or is that an alias?

Comment: @PasserBy - yes, sorry, but the additional level of indirection holds. This is made a bit more troubling by the mixing of C++ and `ble_nus.c`. Please provide [A Minimal Complete Reproducable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to help clear up the confusion.

Comment: Why are you trying to compile c code with a c++ compiler? Why not just use a c compiler, they're separate languages, c++ isn't a superset of c

Comment: Why not show us a snippet of code that will reproduce the error so that we don't have to guess?

Comment: @AlanBirtles _c++ isn't a superset of c_ Ya.  A superset of a subset, and all that.  Hope you had a good Christmas all.

Comment: "How to cast `void*` to `void**`" is almost always the wrong question to ask when the compiler complains that `void*` cannot be converted to `void**`. The compiler is telling you something is wrong, not asking you to interpret it literally and "fix it" by a cast.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`&p_client` is a pointer to a pointer (two-levels).

You cast a pointer to a pointer (two-levels) to a (one-level) pointer.

If you remove the casting of the last parameter, it should work just fine.

Like:

```
ble_nus_client_context_t * p_client = NULL;
err_code = blcm_link_ctx_get(p_nus->p_link_ctx_storage, p_ble_evt->evt.gap_evt.conn_handle, &p_client);
```

Another option is to cast to `void**` as expected.

```
ble_nus_client_context_t * p_client = NULL;
err_code = blcm_link_ctx_get(p_nus->p_link_ctx_storage, p_ble_evt->evt.gap_evt.conn_handle, (void**)&p_client);
```